# Need a function [single or nested] to search for word1 to word2 in a cell and display output1 to output10

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google form for kids asking what they have that they can take to the field, the format of the expected answer is like 
I need to have a formula in place in column C or D that will read the responses and put in the game name.

```
[ column B ]
1 - i have a bat
2 - i have a bat and a ball
3 - i have a basketball 
4 - i have two footballs
5 - i have a rugby ball

[ Column D ]
1 - Cricket
2 - Cricket
3 - Basketball
4 - Football
5 - Rugby
```

I am trying to get this done using `IFs`, `SEARCH` and `REGEXMATCH` but not successful.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B:B, 
 "bat|basketball|football|rugby")), 
 "bat", "cricket")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi, please add some explanation to why this is a solution. Thanks

Comment: Hello everyone,

The above suggested formula is working as I need it to. Thank you for you kind contribution.

I have a few additional concerns about it though. It would be great if d-kennetz or anyone else can explain the process flow or logic flow.

I have been reading about the used functions as well. I also want to know how Rugby and Football are accurately showing up even when they are not defined in the substitute-with list.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: Hello everyone, 

I am facing an additional roadblock now, when I am getting new names of things the kids submit, i am not able to successfully redefine the formula.

Any help?

Comment: @Shom formula works based on regex where from B:B range we try to extract words: `"bat|basketball|football|rugby"` so if any row in B column has one of these words, that word gets imported into D column. under these circumstances, D1 and D2 would be `bat` but you want `cricket` so we perform a `SUBSTITUTE`